# Identifier has " " in name

Tags: button, applescript, identifier

Currently stuck with this. There is a popup menu accessed by right clicking on a track name in the application "Pro Tools". I need to access this menu. After some time I have figured out how to click every other pop up menu on the button apart from one. The first part of the script is to identify the name of the window because it changes depending on the project but I've included it anyway.

Other buttons such as these:

```
    pop up button "Playlist selector"
    button "Track Record Enable"
    button "TrackInput Monitor"
    button "Solo"
    button "Mute"
    pop up button "Track View selector"
    pop up button "Automation Mode selector"
    pop up button "Track options"
```

All work fine.

The only difference is the name of the button.

The button I need is identified in UIElementInspector as

```
pop up button "Track name
        \"Rhythm L\""
```

I believe the issue is caused by the fact there are " " 's in side of another set. When I run the script it says "expected end of line but found identifier"

```
activate application "Pro Tools"
tell application "System Events"
    # Get the frontmost app's *process* object.
    set frontAppProcess to first application process whose frontmost is true
end tell

# Tell the *process* to count its windows and return its front window's name.
tell frontAppProcess
    if (count of windows) > 0 then
        set window_name to name of front window
    end if
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Pro Tools"
    click pop up button "Track name "Rhythm L "" of group "Rhythm L - Audio Track " of window window_name
end tell
```

Comment: You need to escape the quotes in the string, for example `"Track name \"Rhythm L \""`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to have a look. I will give this a go